# PHP MySQL How search in many categories

Tags: php, sql, search

Is there any SQL syntax that allows you to search in many categories, like this:

**Category array:**

```
print_r($category) = Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 24 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 [4] => 27 [5] => 28 [6] => 29 )
```

**Code:**

```
$tab = implode(' OR ', $category);        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE name LIKE '%$what%' AND category = $tab ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT $from , $how_much";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE name LIKE '%$what%' AND category IN ($tab) ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT $from , $how_much";`

You must use "IN".

I must add, if you don't use parameterized queries or PDO, you are open to sql injection vulnerability!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I use WP queries, so i think im safe ?

Comment: I haven't used WP queries, but, it seems like WP sanitises the queries for you.

Comment: I use prepare before sql query. Thanks for help.